# about the order of thread exits and global destruct

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

```
std::string g_string;

void thread_func()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << g_string.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    g_string = "test";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        std::thread t(thread_func);
        t.detach();
    }
}
```

Hi,all.Is there any agreement about the order of global object destructs and thread exits in windows os?
After the destructor destroying the global object,a thread that is still alive accesses the global object g_string, it may cause a crash.Is that right?

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by a) accessing an object after its lifetime has ended, and b) using "a standard library object or function not permitted within signal handlers (18.10) that does not happen before (1.10) completion of destruction of objects with static storage duration and execution of `std::atexit` registered functions" (**3.6.3/4**)

Comment: If you don't want destructors to run, you can do something like `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess()); Sleep(INFINITE);`